# jQuery datepicker - skip certain months

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i need to skip certain months with jQuery datepicker on months selection while using the "prev" and "next" buttons.

This works well when triggering the "next month" button of the datepicker and remapping months when reaching an unwanted month that is not available for selection, but the "previous month" button gives me unusual behaviour and i don't know why...

Let's say i have got valid months/year range like this:

(year, months - no date older than present day)

(2014) 11,12
(2015) 01,02,03,04,05,11,12

Here is my setup of the datepicker (remember internally the datepicker starts counting with a 0 on months)

```
var dateToday = new Date();
        m = dateToday.getMonth();
        y = dateToday.getFullYear();
        jQuery( ".datepickerdiv" ).datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday,
            maxDate: \'+' . $maxDate . 'm\',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: false,
            beforeShowDay: available,
            yearRange: "' . date("Y") . ':' . date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')) . '", 

            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {                    
                jQuery(\'.ui-datepicker-next\').live("click", function() {
                    if(month == 6){
                        year = jQuery(\'select[class=ui-datepicker-year]\').val();  
                        jQuery(\'#anreisedatum\').datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(year, 10, 1));
                        jQuery(\'#anreisedatum\').datepicker("refresh");
                    }
                });

                jQuery(\'.ui-datepicker-prev\').live("click", function() {
                    var selyear = jQuery(\'.ui-datepicker-year\').val();
                    year = jQuery(\'select[class=ui-datepicker-year]\').val(); 

                    if(month == 10 && y < selyear) { 
                        jQuery(\'#anreisedatum\').datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(selyear, 4, 1));
                        jQuery(\'#anreisedatum\').datepicker("refresh");
                    }

                });                    
},dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",showWeek: true,weekHeader: 'KW'...
```

As far it seems the "next"-button just works fine, but there is something strange going on with the "prev"-button. The months are set to for example "may 2015" perfectly when in "nov 2015" and clicking on the "prev"-botton (jumping from "nov 2015" to "may 2015" is correct accoding to the daterange above), but then the button is stuck there.
You can not navigate any earlier than "may 2015" anymore.

Is the standard behaviour of 
    jQuery(\'#anreisedatum\').datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(year, 4, 1));
it's the earliest point possible from that time on?

When that is the case i have to think again about controlling the callendar navigation this way as it just not seem to be possible to skip months display this way... am i right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all of you who are in need of a similar solution here is my approach. I am not happy with it, as it is very static and the eventhandling is a little cheated (due to wrong event stack ordering in my project), but it does the trick.

```
       var dateToday = new Date();
        m = dateToday.getMonth();
        y = dateToday.getFullYear();
        var checkclick;
        jQuery(\'input#edit-submit\').attr("disabled", true);
        jQuery( ".datepickerdiv" ).datepicker({
            minDate: dateToday,
            maxDate: \'+' . $maxDate . 'm\',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: false,
            beforeShowDay: available,
            yearRange: "' . date("Y") . ':' . date('Y', strtotime('+1 year')) . '", 
            beforeShow:function(thisObj)
            {
                jQuery(\'.ui-datepicker-next\').live("click", function() {        
                    checkclick = \'next\';        
                })                    
                jQuery(\'.ui-datepicker-prev\').live("click", function() {
                    checkclick = \'prev\';
                })

            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                year = jQuery(\'select[class=ui-datepicker-year]\').val();  
                if(month == 6 && checkclick==\'next\'){
                    jQuery( this ).datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(year, 10, 1));
                    jQuery( this ).datepicker("refresh");
                }
                if(month == 10 && checkclick==\'prev\'){  
                    if(month==10 && y < year){
                        jQuery( this ).datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(year, 4, 1));
                        jQuery( this ).datepicker("refresh");
                    }
                     if(month==10 && m < month && y == year){
                        jQuery( this ).datepicker( "setDate" , new Date(year, 10, 1));
                        jQuery( this ).datepicker("refresh");
                    }
                }

},firstDay: ' . $weekday . ',dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",showWeek: true,weekHeader: \'KW\'...
```

I hope this is useful to some of you, as i could not find any native way on the datepicker API to get this done.